# HighCharts negative color for dataLabels

Tags: highcharts

In HighCharts series can have a color (black) and a negativeColor (red) for positive and negative values easy like this:

```
series: {
  color: 'black',
  negativeColor: 'red'
```

Is there an easy way to do the same for the labels?

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: black
        //no negativeColor...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in option like that. Still, you can define a data label for each point and set a proper color if the value is negative.

```
data: data.map(function (point) {
            return point < 0 
            ? {y: point, dataLabels: {color: 'black'}} 
            : point;
        })
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/s8ay794r/1/